# htaccess ssl request and query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

htacces:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I want pass all arguments from url to my script (there i parse url and redirect user to http or https) and everthink work fine when i use http//:mydomain.com/register.html but when i try use https//:mydomain.com/register.html the apache drop 404 not found

Comment: Ok problem was fixed. Just was wrong directory set in apache httpd-ssl-conf file in <VirtualHost mydomain.com:443>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/domainfolder/"

Comment: You might consider using `QSA` flag rather the manually trying to build URL with query string value.  This is much easier down the line should you want to do something like redirect to a page while adding a parameter like `RewriteRUle .* index.php?foo-bar [L,QSA]` as then any parameters in initial query string would just be added to the one you created.